# Distributing a vdi with ROS pre-installed

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I built an Ubuntu12.04LTS virtual machine and i use it with Oracle VirtualBox. I had downloaded the corresponding .iso from the official site, converted that into a virtual machine. So, with Ubuntu as guest OS, i have then installed ROS hydro and it works perfectly.
My question is what is the correct way to distribute this virtual machine so that others can benefit from it? Since now i have a machine name and credentials, i am wondering what is the right way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/85871/distributing-a-vdi-with-ros-pre-installed/) by [mbkv](https://answers.ros.org/users/605/mbkv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-10-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have an image you would like to distribute you can post it online and send people links. A few others have done this before and written blog posts to share it.

There are many places which will host large files.  Dropbox is a common service for that.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0